# NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource() why not enter in section of if?

Tags: ios, swift, nsbundle

[image]

`NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource()` why not enter in section of if?

Comment: Do not post an image of your code. Copy and paste the actual code into your question (and be sure you format it properly).

Comment: And why all of the breakpoints? Use only the 1st one and then single step if you wish to stop at each line.

Answer (score 2):

The argument to the `ofType` parameter of the `pathForResource` function needs to be a filename extension, not a mime-type. So you probably just want `"xml"`, not `"text/xml"`.

Comment: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MARIO.xml", ofType: nil)) ,  NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MARIO", ofType: "xml"))  NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MARIO.xml", ofType: "text/xml"))  NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MARIO", ofType: "text/xml"))   ALL NOT WORK

Comment: Then you don't actually have a file named `MARIO.xml` in your app's resource bundle.

Comment: ///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/...../Documents/MARIO.xml --- archivo:: /// archivo privado / var / mobile / Contenedores / datos / aplicaciones / ..... ... / Documentos / archivo MARIO2.xml:--- ///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/...../Documents/SingleViewCoreData.sqlite archivo: /// privado / var / mobile / Contenedores / Los datos / documentos / aplicación /...../ SingleViewCoreData.sqlite-SHM archivo:---///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../Documents/fuck.xml--  This is what I have in my Directory

Comment: I'm not sure what that mess is supposed to be but I still don't see a `MARIO.xml` file in your app bundle. I see one in the Documents folder though. But that's not the app's resource bundle.

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](https://www.centerdevice.de/wp-content/uploads/appsandbox.png) </br> The file was created , I keep in Documents